# Classic ASP: Illogical If Statement Result

Tags: if-statement, asp-classic, logic

```vbs
response.Write("CurPage=" & CurPage & "<br />")
response.Write("iNumPages=" & iNumPages)
if CurPage < iNumPages then
    response.Write("in correct part")
    writepagebar = sStr & sLink & CurPage + 1 & """ rel=""next"">" _
      & snext & "</a> " & sLink & iNumPages & """><span class=""pagebarquo""" _
      & " style=""font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold"">&raquo;</span></a>"
else
    response.Write("in bad part")
    writepagebar = sStr & " " & snext & " <span class=""pagebarquo""" _
       & " style=""font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold"">&raquo;</span>"
end if
```

What is wrong here?  It's printing out

> CurPage=11
> iNumPages=52

So it should be going into the correct part...but it's going into the bad part.

[image: screenshot]

I'm trying to make the **Next** word a hyper link...

Comment: probably `CurPage` is evaluating as `String`. In VBScript `"11" < 52` expression returns `False`. try to replace your condition with `if CLng(CurPage) < CLng(iNumPages) then` and observe. don't forget to cast numeric variables into an appropriate type using CDbl, CLng vs CInt etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `CurPage` is evaluating as `String`. 
Since it is possible to have a `False` return value for an expression like `"11" < 52` in VBScript, before comparing numeric variables you should make sure that its data type is also numeric, not string. 
This will work as you expect.

```vb
if CLng(CurPage) < CLng(iNumPages) then
    'correct part
else
    'bad part
end if
```